# PHP Split Problem

Tags: php, split, preg-split

I am trying to use (and I've tried both) preg_split() and split() and neither of these have worked for me. Here are the attempts and outputs.

```
preg_split("^", "ItemOne^ItemTwo^Item.Three^");
//output - null or false when attempting to implode() it.
preg_split("\^", "ItemOne^ItemTwo^Item.Three^");
//output - null or false when attempting to implode() it. Attempted to escape the needle.
//SAME THING WITH split().
```

Thanks for your help...
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` is deprecated.  You should use `explode`

`$arr = explode('^', "ItemOne^ItemTwo^Item.Three^");`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
explode("^", "ItemOne^ItemTwo^Item.Three^");
```

since your search pattern isn't a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not just looking for `explode`?

`explode('^', 'ItemOne^ItemTwo^Item.Three^');`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `preg_split` you are trying to split the string by a given regular expresion. The circumflex (^) is a regular expression metacharacter and therefore not working in your example.

btw: preg_split is an alternative to split and not deprecated.